# Deep freeze, shower water is just dripping

Tags: plumbing, pipe, freezing

We are going thru a deep freeze (-9F). The shower upstairs is just dripping hot water, should I leave it dripping in hope that it will eventually melt the blockage, or should I completely shut down water in the house.

Comment: let it drip''''

Answer (score 2):

If you are having freezing-pipe problems, you should either keep water running or drain the pipes.

Running water, even running cold water, will generally be warm enough not to freeze easily. Underground usually settles at or near the yearly average temperature for the region, which for most of us is above freezing. As long as you keep that warmer water coming through, it can help keep the pipes warm enough not to freeze solid. A trickle may be sufficient for that. Hot water is better for this purpose, of course.

It's when the water stops moving and starts freezing all the way through -- and then continuing to expand -- that you get burst pipes.

The other solution is to drain the affected pipes so there isn't any water in them to freeze.

If your house is still heated, the pipes most at risk are going to be the ones that run outside the heat envelope -- pipes in outside walls and don't have much insulation between them and outside are a classic example.

Answer (score 0):

Close the main valve to the house, turn off the water heater and open all faucets to give the water that's not yet frozen a "place to go".  When decent temps return, be sure to run all faucets until no more air comes out, (esp. important for hot water faucets), then turn on the WH ....it's been a continent event right now.